# Formatting my css drop down menu

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, menu

I like the look of [this](http://www.zkoss.org/product/zkstudio/demo) menu

I can't figure out how to get a line below each of the drop down elements without it going all the way to the edge and looking like a table layout. I'm thinking padding needs to be added in somewhere, but I can't figure out where.

[This](http://cssdesk.com/V7sKE) is what I have so far.

Part II of this question is what code would I need to introduce to add a third level to this menu?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the border-bottom from `#centeredmenu ul ul li`

Put it in `#centeredmenu ul ul li a` and add some `margin-left` and `margin-right`;

Answer (score 0):

Move the left and right borders from `#centeredmenu ul ul li a` to `#centeredmenu ul ul li` and move the bottom border from `#centeredmenu ul ul li` to `#centeredmenu ul ul li a`

Add margin to `#centeredmenu ul ul li a` and then add a bottom border to `#centeredmenu ul ul` to fill the gaps on the last item.

[I've updated your example here](http://cssdesk.com/ksf9J)